# Error in File Type check in MultipartConfig

Tags: java, servlets

Am develop code for upload images. but that not work properly. in my `servlet` i will check `contenttype` if `contexttype` match to `"image/jpeg"` or  `"image/jpeg"` the file will write other wise show an error message

```
 Part filePart = request.getPart("pho`to");
 String str = filePart.getContentType();

 if (str != "image/jpeg" && str != "image/jpg") {
     response.sendRedirect("uploadimage?action=errorinfiletype");
     return;
 }

User.updateImage(inputStream, uid);
response.sendRedirect("uploadimage?action=changed");
```

but the above code always shows the error message.
i think error in my if condition. anybody please help

Comment: what is the error you are getting? compile time or runtime error?

Comment: there is no error. always enter to the body of the if

Comment: what is your expectation and what is your concern on this?

Comment: if str equals  this "image/jpeg"  or "image/jpg" . then update image otherwise print error message

Comment: instead of && use ||. Here && expects both the conditions should be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
if (str==null || !str.matches("image/jp(e)?g") ) {
        response.sendRedirect("uploadimage?action=errorinfiletype");
        return;
}
```

Comment: but as the original code is messy anyway, not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you cannot compare strings using the `==` or `!=` operator. You have to use the `equals()` method, i.e.

```
if (!"image/jpeg".equals(str) && !"image/jpg".equals(str)) {
    ...
}
```